# Java Mysql Prepared statement syntax issue

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

I am getting a syntax error with the SQL code within a prepared statement. I have read the other answers on the site and I cannot work out the issue. My code is as follows

```
     private boolean validate_login(String username,String password) {
   try{           
       Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  // MySQL database connection
       String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/db_webstore";
       String user = "root";
       String pw = "Password";




      String SQL = "select * from tbl-users where Tbl-UsersUserName=? and Tbl-UsersPassword=?";


        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pw);
        PreparedStatement pst;
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(SQL);
        pst.setString(1, username); 
       pst.setString(2, password);
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();                        

        if(rs.next())            
           return true;    
       else
           return false;            
   }
   catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
       return false;
   }       


    }
```

The error message is as follows

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-users where Tbl-UsersYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-users where Tbl-Users

Can anyone offer some advice? Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can we have tbl-users structure ?

Comment: is tbl-users valid table name?

Comment: @anaspa Doesn't look to be valid: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html

Comment: @richard-faint has this question been answered for you? If yes, would you mind to accept the most helpful answer to mark this question as solved (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers))... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably missing some dots in your query. Table and column name need to be separated by a dot. Furthermore the table name needs to be quoted as `-` is not allowed in unquoted identifiers (see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html)):

```
 String SQL = "select * from `Tbl-Users`"
        + " where `Tbl-Users`.UserName=?"
        + "   and `Tbl-Users`.Password=?";
```

---

**UPDATE**:

- Added link to MySQL docu on valid identifiers
- Quoted table name using `

Answer (score 0):

you should include the port number(which is `3306` for `MySQL`) in your database connection

accordingly your code should be corrected as follows

```
private boolean validate_login(String username,String password) {
   try{           
       Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  // MySQL database connection
       String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_webstore";
       String user = "root";
       String pw = "Password";




      String SQL = "select * from tbl-users where Tbl-UsersUserName=? and Tbl-UsersPassword=?";


        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pw);
        PreparedStatement pst;
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(SQL);
        pst.setString(1, username); 
       pst.setString(2, password); 
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();                        

        if(rs.next())            
           return true;    
       else
           return false;            
   }
   catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
       return false;
   }       


    }
```